# GNU awk: accessing captured groups in replacement text

Tags: gawk

This seems like it should be dirt simple, but the awk gensub/gsub/sub behavior has always been unclear to me, and now I just can't get it to do what the documentation says it should do (and what experience with a zillion other similar tools suggests should work).  Specifically, I want to access "captured groups" from a regex in the replacement string.  Here's what I think the awk syntax should be:

```
awk '{ gsub(/a(b*)c/, "Here are bees: \1"); print; }'
```

That should turn "abbbc" into "Here are bees: bbb".  It does not, at least not for me in Ubunutu 9.04.  Instead, the "\1" is rendered as a ^A; that is, the character with code 1.  Not what I want, of course. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
echo abbc | awk '{ print gensub(/a(b*)c/, "Here are bees: \\1", "g", $1);}'
```

See manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions) to see the difference between gsub and gensub

> gensub() provides an additional feature that is not available in sub()
> or gsub(): the ability to specify components of a regexp in the
> replacement text. This is done by using parentheses in the regexp to
> mark the components and then specifying ‘\N’ in the replacement text,
> where N is a digit from 1 to 9.

Comment: Also, not only to gsub and gensub behave differently with respect to return value, but the whole \1 through \9 feature *only* works with gensub.

Comment: Try `echo xxxabbcxxx` - the awk "solution" breaks

Comment: @Alesandr, feel free to propose a new one

Comment: @AleksandrLevchuk Your example works exactly as expected. I see nothing wrong with this solution. It makes the substitution, then returns the full variable(s).

Comment: It's hilarious to me to see someone state that a language is "broken" because they didn't understand the syntax or read the manual!

Comment: Useful to know how to get the [entire search matched text](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions):

`As with sub(), you must type two backslashes in order to get one into the string. In the replacement text, the sequence ‘\0’ represents the entire matched text, as does the character ‘&’.`

Answer (score 31):

Per the gawk manual

> gensub provides an additional feature
>   that is not available in sub or gsub:
>   the ability to specify components of a
>   regexp in the replacement text. This
>   is done by using parentheses in the
>   regexp to mark the components and then
>   specifying ‘\N’ in the replacement
>   text, where N is a digit from 1 to 9.

You must use gensub, you must specify "g", and you must grab the **result** of gensub, since it does not modify in-place.

```
awk '{ r = gensub(/a(b*)c/, "Here are bees: \\1", "g"); print r; }'
```