# AWK: Access captured group from line pattern

Tags: regex, awk

If I have an awk command

```
pattern { ... }
```

and pattern uses a capturing group, how can I access the string so captured in the block?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555173/gnu-awk-accessing-captured-groups-in-replacement-text

Comment: Sometimes (in simple cases) it's possible to adjust the field separator (`FS`) and pick what one would like to match with a `$field`. Preformatting the input could help too.

Comment: There is a [better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10254791/894885) on the duplicate question.

Comment: Samuel Edwin Ward: That's a nice answer too! But it also requires `gawk` (since it uses `gensub`).

Comment: Needless to say, if you're doing a simple transform, sed handles capture groups quite naturally.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

That was a stroll down memory lane...

I replaced awk by perl a long time ago.

Apparently the AWK regular expression engine does not capture its groups.

you might consider using something like :

```
perl -n -e'/test(\d+)/ && print $1'
```

the -n flag causes perl to loop over every line like awk does.

Comment: Apparently someone disagrees. This web page is from 2005 : http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5674

It confirms that you cannot reuse matched groups in awk.

Comment: [this article](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/ten-awk-tips-tricks-and-pitfalls/) seems to agree with you too.

Comment: As the tek-tips article states, gawk can re-use capture groups.

Comment: I prefer 'perl -n -p -e...' over awk for almost all use cases, since it is more flexible, more powerful and has a saner syntax in my opinion.

Comment: `gawk` != `awk`. They're different tools and `gawk` isn't available by default in most places.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for an awk solution, so I don't think this is an answer.

Comment: @Joppe you can't give an awk solution if there is no solution. In line 3 I explain that AWK does not support capturing groups and I gave an alternative, which the OP apparently appreciated because this answer was accepted. How could I better answer this question?

Comment: @famousgarkin I keep forgetting Perl for the same reasons I still use grep and/or cut instead of awk: I build up long commands incrementally. And I sometimes have some vague idea that it matters that Perl is larger than grep/awk.

Comment: Be aware that `perl -p`/`-n` internally uses the `<>` operator, that has a "feature" that interprets filenames ending with `|` as commands, and truncates files starting with `>`. See [here](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/05/use-perl-5-22s-operator-for-safe-command-line-handling/).

Comment: I think the major issue is that the manual page for `awk` explains for the regular expression syntax that "grouping" is supported, but it says **very little** about *how to use groups*. All it says is: "*Grouping: matches r.*"

Comment: @Joppe, You are factually incorrect; he did answer it: "the AWK regular expression engine does not capture its groups."  Whether you agree with the answer or not is irrelevant, as is the fact that the author also added an alternative (in **addition to his answer**), which happens all the time on SO, and is useful for some people.

Answer (score 434):

With gawk, you can use the `match` function to capture parenthesized groups.

```
gawk 'match($0, pattern, ary) {print ary[1]}'
```

example:

```
echo "abcdef" | gawk 'match($0, /b(.*)e/, a) {print a[1]}'
```

outputs `cd`.

Note the specific use of gawk which implements the feature in question.

For a portable alternative you can achieve similar results with `match()` and `substr`.

example:

```
echo "abcdef" | awk 'match($0, /b[^e]*/) {print substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1)}'
```

outputs `cd`.

Comment: Yes, the gxxx variants have lots of additional GNU goodness and power.

Comment: Works in BusyBox awk as well.

Answer (score 38):

This is something I need all the time so I created a bash function for it. It's based on glenn jackman's answer.

### Definition

Add this to your .bash_profile etc.

```
function regex { gawk 'match($0,/'$1'/, ary) {print ary['${2:-'0'}']}'; }
```

### Usage

Capture regex for each line in file

```
$ cat filename | regex '.*'
```

Capture 1st regex capture group for each line in file

```
$ cat filename | regex '(.*)' 1
```

Comment: How is it different from using `grep -o`?

Comment: @bfontaine Could `grep -o` output captured groups?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt No it couldn’t. It only covers your use-case when you don’t have capture-groups. In that case it gets ugly with chained `grep -o`'s.

Comment: this needs support for multiple captures

Answer (score 20):

You can use GNU awk:

```
$ cat hta
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.net/$1 [R=301,L]

$ gawk 'match($0, /.*(http.*?)\$/, m) { print m[1]; }' < hta
http://www.mysite.net/
```

Comment: That's [what glenn jackman's answer says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4673336/9859), pretty much.

Comment: Ed Morton: that deserves a top-level answer I'd say.  edit: uhm... that prints `RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.net/$` for me, which is more than the subgroup.

Comment: [Looks like `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` refer to the substring matched by the pattern](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-47)

Comment: @EdMorton - no, that will select the whole line that contains `http...` pattern

Comment: @KFL you're right but actually there's a worse problem that the posted answer (and my suggestion to make it not gawk-specific) both contain `.*?` which is a PCRE-ism and undefined behavior in an ERE. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 7):

*NOTE: the use of `gensub` is not POSIX compliant*

You can simulate capturing in vanilla awk too, without extensions. Its not intuitive though:

step 1. use gensub to surround matches with some character that doesnt appear in your string.
step 2. Use split against the character.
step 3. Every other element in the splitted array is your capture group.

```
$ echo 'ab cb ad' | awk '{ split(gensub(/a./,SUBSEP"&"SUBSEP,"g",$0),cap,SUBSEP); print cap[2]"|" cap[4] ; }'
ab|ad
```

Comment: I'm almost certain that `gensub` is a `gawk` specific function. What do you get from your awk if you type `awk --version` ;-?). Good luck to all.

Comment: I'm fully certain that gensub is a gawk-ism, though BusyBox awk also has it. This answer could also be implemented using gsub, though: `echo 'ab cb ad' | awk '{gsub(/a./,SUBSEP"&"SUBSEP);split($0,cap,SUBSEP);print cap[2]"|"cap[4]}'`

Comment: gensub() is a gawk extension, gawk's manual clearly say so. Other awk variants may also implement it, but it is still not POSIX. Try gawk --posix '{gsub(...)}' and it will complain

Comment: @MestreLion, you mean it will complain for `gawk --posix '{gensub(...)}'`.

Comment: @dubiousjim: oops, yes, `gensub()`, sorry for the typo

Comment: Despite you were wrong about **POSIX awk** having the `gensub` function, your example applied to a very limited scenario: the whole pattern is grouped, it can't match something like all `key=(value)` when I want to extract only the `value` parts.

Comment: Enough people have commented about "gensub is a gawk-ism".  Why not edit your answer at least?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled a bit with coming up with a bash function that wraps Peter Tillemans' answer but here's what I came up with:

> function regex
>   { 
>       perl -n -e "/$1/ && printf \"%s\n\", "'$1'
>   }

I found this worked better than opsb's awk-based bash function for the following regular expression argument, because I do not want the "ms" to be printed.

```
'([0-9]*)ms$'
```

Comment: I prefer this solution, since you can see the parts of the group that delimit the capture, while also omitting them.  However, could someone elxplain how this works?  I can't get this perl syntax to work properly in BASH, because I don't understand it very well - especially the double/single-quote marks around `$1`

Comment: It is not something I have done before or since, but looking back what it is doing is concatenating two strings, the first string being in double quotes (this first string contains embedded double quotes escaped with backslash) and the second string being in single quotes.  Then the result of that concatenation is supplied as argument to perl -e.  Also you need to know that the first $1 (the one within double quotes) is substituted with the first argument to the function, while the second $1 (the one within single quotes) is left untouched. See [this example](https://i.imgur.com/Bfp2TmA.png)

Comment: I see, that's making a bit more sense now.  So where in the perl command is the regex match/group capture definition?  I see you wrote `'([0-9]*)ms$'` - is that supplied as an argument (and the string another argument)?   And the output from `perl -e` is being inserted into bash's `printf` command then, to replace `%s`, is that right?  Thanks, I am hoping to use this.

Comment: You pass a regular expression enclosed in single quotes as the sole argument to the regex bash function. [Example](https://i.imgur.com/71UKj52.png)

Comment: I downvoted because the question asks about awk so this answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

i think gawk match()-to-array is only for first instance of the capture group.

if there are multiple things you'd like to capture, and perform any complex operations upon them, perhaps

```
gawk 'BEGIN { S = SUBSEP 
          } { 
              nx=split(gensub(/(..(..)..(..))/, 
                              "\\1"(S)"\\2"(S)"\\3", "g", str), 
                       arr, S)
              for(x in nx) { perform-ops-over arr[x] } }'
```

This way you aren't constrained by either `gensub()`, which limits the complexity if your modifications, or by `match()`.

by pure trial-and-error, one caveat i've noted about gawk in unicode mode : for a valid unicode string **뀇꿬** with the 6 octal codes listed below :

> Scenario 1 : matching individual bytes are fine, but will also report you the multi-byte RSTART of 1 instead of a byte-level answer of 2. It also won't provide info on whether **\207** is the 1st continuation byte, or the second one, since RLENGTH will always be 1 here.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{ print match("\353\200\207\352\277\254", "\207") }' 
$ 1
```

> Scenario 2 : Match also works against unicode-invalid patterns like this

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{ match("\353\200\207\352\277\254", "\207\352"); 
$                print RSTART, RLENGTH }' 
$ 1 2
```

> Scenario 3 : you can check for existence of a pattern against a unicode-illegal string (**\300 \xC0** is UTF8-invalid for all possible byte pairings)

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{ print ("\300\353\200\207\352\277\254" ~ /\200/) }' 
$ 1
```

> Scenarios 4/5/6 : the error message will show up for either (a) `match()` with unicode-invalid string, `index()` for either argument to be unicode-invalid/incomplete.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{ match("\300\353\200\207\352\277\254", "\207\352"); print RSTART, RLENGTH }' gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data and your locale. 2 2

$ gawk 'BEGIN{ print index("\353\200\207\352\277\254", "\352") }' gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data and your locale. 0

$ gawk 'BEGIN{ print index("\353\200\207\352\277\254", "\200") }' gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data and your locale. 0
```