# Extracting each line from a file and passing it as a variable to "foreach" loop

Tags: python, regex, linux, sed

Could somebody help me figure out a simple way of doing this using any script ? I will be running the script on Linux

1 ) I have a file1 which has the following lines :

```
 (Bank8GntR[3] | Bank8GntR[2] | Bank8GntR[1] | Bank8GntR[0] ),

 (Bank7GntR[3] | Bank7GntR[2] | Bank7GntR[1] | Bank7GntR[0] ),

 (Bank6GntR[3] | Bank6GntR[2] | Bank6GntR[1] | Bank6GntR[0] ),

 (Bank5GntR[3] | Bank5GntR[2] | Bank5GntR[1] | Bank5GntR[0] ),
```

2 ) I need the contents of file1 to be modified as following and written to a file2

```
 (Bank15GntR[3] | Bank15GntR[2] | Bank15GntR[1] | Bank15GntR[0] ),

 (Bank14GntR[3] | Bank14GntR[2] | Bank14GntR[1] | Bank14GntR[0] ),

 (Bank13GntR[3] | Bank13GntR[2] | Bank13GntR[1] | Bank13GntR[0] ),

 (Bank12GntR[3] | Bank12GntR[2] | Bank12GntR[1] | Bank12GntR[0] ),
```

So I have to:

1. read each line from the file1,
2. use "search" using regular expression,
3. to match Bank[0-9]GntR,
4. replace \1 with "7 added to number matched",
5. insert it back into the line,
6. write the line into a new file.

Comment: You haven't replaced it with "number matched multiplied 2", you've just added 7 to each.

Comment: sorry ! i just realized that and made the changes

Comment: Do you have to use python? Or can it be anything? Your tags mention `sed` and you stress the point that it's a script running on Linux, so I'm not sure on whether it *has* to be in Python.

Comment: actually it can be anything ... does not have to by python.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this in Python:

```
# a function that adds 7 to a matched group.
# groups 1 and 2, we grabbed (Bank) to avoid catching the digits in brackets.
def plus7(matchobj):
  return '%s%d' % (matchobj.group(1), int(matchobj.group(2)) + 7)

# iterate over the input file, have access to the output file.
with open('in.txt') as fhi, open('out.txt', 'w') as fho:
  for line in fhi:
    fho.write(re.sub('(Bank)(\d+)', plus7, line))
```

Comment: Notes:  `with` only supports one file handle prior to 2.7.  You'd need to nest two statements if you're working with anything <= 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have to use python, you can do this using `awk`:

```bsh
cat test.txt | awk 'match($0, /Bank([0-9]+)GntR/, nums) { d=nums[1]+7; gsub(/Bank[0-9]+GntR\[/, "Bank" d "GntR["); print }'
```

This gives the desired output.

The point here is that `match` will match your data and allows *capturing groups* which you can use to extract out the number. As awk supports arithmetic, you can then add 7 within awk and then do a replacement on all the values in the rest of the line. Note, I've assumed all the values in the line have the same digit in them.

Comment: Wow ! this works like a charm. i could have never come up this with my rudimentary knowledge in awk. thanks a lot !!

Comment: I actually had to look up how to get awk to allow me to use capturing groups myself. I found the following comment - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957684/awk-access-captured-group-from-line-pattern/4673336#4673336 which was very helpful!

Comment: Thanks ! pretty useful link !!