# awk: any way to access the matched groups in action?

Tags: awk

I often find myself doing the same match in the action as the pattern, to access some part of the input record, e.g.

```
/^Compiled from \"(.*)\"$/ {
    file_name = gensub("^Compiled from \"(.*)\"$", "\\1", "g");
    print file_name;
}
```

So the regexp matching is done twice. Is there any way I can access `\\1` in the action without matching again?

I am trying to both reduce on pattert matching and extra code.

Comment: seems like answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957684/awk-access-captured-group-from-line-pattern

Comment: @Slartibartfast it helps. I did not find that question before posting, so thanks. Still, as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4673336/18573) answer I have to use the `match($0....` which is kind of ugly though not really

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, GAWK, doesn't have the carry-forward feature of `sed` which uses an empty `//`.

```
sed '/\(patt\)ern/ {s//new\1/}' inputfile
```

However, you can rejoice since variables have recently been invented and they can be used for just this purpose!

```
BEGIN {
    pattern = "^Compiled from \"(.*)\"$"
}
$0 ~ pattern {
    file_name = gensub(pattern, "\\1", "");
    print file_name;
}
```

Comment: I had already been using variables but I am accepting this as it answers my question.