# awk: Counting errors in tomcat logs

Tags: regex, tomcat, logging, awk

My Tomcat logs are build in this format:

```
[<DATE>] [<COMPONENT>] ERROR_TYPE <ERROR_NAME> - <Rest of line>
```

Where `ERROR_TYPE` is [a log4j value](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html) like `DEBUG` or `ERROR`.

e.g.,

```
[18/Jul/2012:08:53:39 +0000] [component1] ERROR ConnectionTimeOut - ...
[18/Jul/2012:09:54:32 +0000] [component2] DEBUG IPNotFound - ...
[18/Jul/2012:09:54:32 +0000] [component1] TRACE Connected - ...
[18/Jul/2012:08:53:39 +0000] [component1] ERROR ConnectionTimeOut - ...
```

I would like to create a maps from the tuple `(ERROR_TYPE, ERROR_NAME)` to the number of occurrences, e.g.

```
ERROR ConnectionTimeOut       2
DEBUG IPNotFound              1
TRACE Connected               1
```

How do I match something like:

```
_anything_ (ERROR|DEBUG|TRACE|WARN|FATAL_spaces_ _another_word_)_anything_
```

in AWK, and return only the part in parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '/ERROR|DEBUG|TRACE|WARN|FATAL/ {count[$4,$5]++} END {for (i in count) {split(i, a, SUBSEP); print a[1], a[2], count[i]}}' inputfile
```

Lines are selected which contain the error types. A `count` array element is incremented for the type and name taken together as the index. The comma represents the contents of the `SUBSEP` variable which defaults to `\034`. In the `END` block, iterate over the `count` array, splitting the indices using the `SUBSEP` variable. Print the type, name and count.

**Edit:**

This uses a regex to handle unstructured log entries:

```
awk 'match($0, /(ERROR|DEBUG|TRACE|WARN|FATAL) +[^ ]+/) {s = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); split(s, a); count[a[1],a[2]]++} END {for (i in count) {split(i, a, SUBSEP); print a[1], a[2], count[i]}}' inputfile
```

Comment: The logs are often unstructured, so I can't use expressions like `$4`. I want to match only two word, regardless of what happens before or after.

Comment: The `split` function should be `split(i, a, SUBSEP)` to get indexes, not values.

Comment: @AdamMatan: With unstructured data, it's a bit more complicated. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957684/awk-access-captured-group-from-line-pattern). Depends on the AWK flavor. You might be better off with Ruby or Perl, if you can.

Comment: Thanks! The log is indeed unstructured, so I turned to Python.