# Does unix command awk have the similar funcation like java.util.regex.Matcher.group(int)?

Tags: java, regex, unix

Matching the whole line cannot meet my requirement. I want to match the specific line like below.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*you\\[)(\\w+\\-\\w+\\-\\w+)(\\]\\:\\slove\\:\\s)(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern .matcher(line);
System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
```

I want to know how can I do it using `awk` or other Unix command. I want to match specific group, for example

```
his number is 123 and his name is jack.
```

I want to get the `123` and `jack` after matching the whole line successfully. This is regex above

```
(.*\\s)(\d+\s)(.*)(\\s.*)
```

Than I can get number using group(2). But how can I get it using awk?

Comment: It isn't very clear what you want to match since you said that your regex doesn't work.

Comment: Sample input/output along with the expected output, will tell more as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to match specific group, for example, his number is 123 and his name is jack. I want to get the number and name after matching the whole line successfully.

Comment: possible duplicate of [awk: access captured group from line pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957684/awk-access-captured-group-from-line-pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo "his number is 123 and his name is jack" | perl -ne 'print "$1\n$2\n$3\n$4" if /(.*\s)(\d+\s)(.*?)\s([^\s]*$)/'
```

would give the following output :

---

```
his number is 
123 
and his name is
jack
```

Here $2 and $4 holds the number and the name respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
awk '{print $4,$9}' FPAT='[0-9a-z]*'
```