# awk matches regex characters it shouldn't

Tags: regex, awk

My awk program does some odd character matching. Could you please explain what's going on or point me to relevant documentation.

**Input file**

```
| 29900 | St. James | ...
| 33010 | Boole / Kirk | ...
```

**awk**

```
awk '/\| ([0-9]{5}) \| ([^\|]*)/{print $2 $4}' input-file.txt
```

**Result**

```
29900St.
33010Boole
```

- Why is the first capturing group $1 the leading `|`? Usually $0 is the entire match and $1 is the first group.
- Why does `([^\|]*)` stop at `.` and `/` instead of reading on? I basically tell it "all characters that are not |" after all.

Comment: `$2` and `$4` aren't capture groups, they're columns of the input file.

Comment: And it looks like awk -F' | ' would be simpler than trying to use regexes here...

Comment: @Barmar, hhmm...right. Then how can I split a line according to the regex and print the captured values?

Comment: @SteveHoward, thanks. That helps. Still, `awk` doesn't just split at `|` but also at `.` and `/`.

Comment: Use the `-F` option to specify a regular expression to split the line into fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, awk separates columns by whitespace, so for the record

```
| 29900 | St. James | ...
```

we have $1="|", $2="29900", $3="|", $4="St.", $5="James", $6="|" and $7="..."

Additionally, unlike Perl, awk does not store the contents of capturing parentheses anywhere ([gawk does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957684/awk-access-captured-group-from-line-pattern/4673336#4673336) though)

Seeing as you want to use pipes as separators, I'd suggest:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]]*' -v OFS=, '$2 ~ /[0-9]{5}/ {print $2,$3}'
```

```
29900,St. James
33010,Boole / Kirk
```

If you're confused about seeing $2 and $3 in there instead of $1 and $2, consider that a field separator, by definition, separates two fields and must have a field before it and after it. The first field separator shows up at the beginning of each line, therefore there must be a field consisting of an empty string before it: $1 will be the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` doesn't provide a way to access capture groups, it uses `$<number>` to access fields of the input file. It looks like you could do:

```
awk -F' *\| *' '{print $2 $3;}' input-file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, if I make this `' *\\| *'` it works. Maybe because I'm on OS X.

Comment: Yeah, I was having trouble getting it to work on my OS X system, too. My answer worked on Linux, so I posted it that way. I'm not sure why it needs the extra slash on OS X.

Comment: On Ubuntu I get this error: `awk: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|'`