# Search for few alternatives in one regex

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to create a regex that will match the begining of my string in few alternatives.

1. If the whole string contains no `/` then match `^[a-zA-Z\-]`
2. If the string contains `/` then match `^[\w]` until the first occurence of `/`

examples:

```
__Gi0__/0/0/0
__BVI__10
```

The match needs to be returned so I want to wrap it in `()`

I have tried these

```
([a-zA-Z]+)|([\-\w]{2,}/)
```

but it doesnt match second case.

Any suggestions?

My awk version is `GNU Awk 4.0.0`

Comment: you'll need to include more info about your `awk` version. If you running on AIX or older Unix we'll need to know that too. Good luck. (Best to edit  your question with this info, as you may know).

Comment: A dew hints about the regex you used: It's not anchored, so the first group will match everything before a slash and the second group will never be used. Also note that inside a character range `[]` you dont have to escape special characters (besides `]`).

Comment: What do you mean by `The match needs to be returned`? There are no awk functions or language constructs that return a string matching an RE (e.g. replace some text in a string or populate an array). There are functions that do other things with a matched RE so if you provide more info we can help you come up with the best solution. Also, the issue with providing solutions to these types of questions is never matching what you want, it's NOT matching what you DON'T want so post more interesting input and expected output or you might get a buggy "solution".

Comment: @Ed Morton I'm using gawk and the match function in gawk is able to populate an array. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4673336/1839439 . sshashank124 understood my problem and provided the answer I needed so I don't think I need to provide any more input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it as:

`^((\w+)\/|([a-zA-Z_-]+))`

Second captured group contains what you want.

Or as @Jenny suggested, you can make the first group non-capturing as follows:

`^(?:(\w+)\/|([a-zA-Z_-]+))`

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/fG9rL2)

Comment: But if there is no `/` in the string then the numbers should not be matched.

Comment: Note that spaces do not exist in the strings

Comment: Your answer works but the `/` is also included in my capture group which I don't want.

Comment: @Dharman, Please note as I stated in my answer. The __2nd__ captured group \2 or $2 will contain the string you want.

Comment: But when I use the second group I lose the ones without `/` eg. **BVI**

Comment: Ok nvm I joined the results of the two groups together it works now

Comment: @Dharman. Regex in my answer updated. Sorry for the trouble. I'm sure it works now

Comment: You may add ?: after the first ( to disable capturing of the first group.

Comment: This question was tagged for `awk` but the accepted solution won't work in most awks since `\w` is gawk-specific. The second one with `?:` intended to mean something won't work in any awk at all. Why not just use POSIX character classes `^(([[:alnum:]_]+)\/|([[:alpha:]_-]+))`? Also `The match needs to be returned so I want to wrap it in ()` only has meaning within a call to gensub() and gawk match() so hopefully that's where you're using the RE.