# Using matched pattern in awk

Tags: regex, awk

I want to print the matched pattern using awk.  Not the field, not the line.

In vi, you can put the matched pattern in the substitution by surrounding it with parens and referencing it with curly braces and a number, like this:

```
:s/bufid=([0-9]*)/buffer id is {\0}/
```

The part that matches between parens is remembered and can be used.

In perl, it is similar

```
$_ = "Hello there, neighbor";
if (/\s(\w+),/) {             # memorize the word between space and comma
  print "the word was $1\n";  # the word was there
}
```

Is there any way I can do something similar with awk?  I just want to extract the buffer id and print it, and only it.

The input line is XML, and will contain (among other things) 'bufId="123456"'.  I want to print "123456"

so ...

```
awk < file.xml '/bufId="([0-9]*)"/ { print X; }'
```

What do I put where X is?

Can this even be done?

Comment: The closest I have found to doing what I want is this compound:

    grep 'bufId="[0-9]*"'  | sed 's/^.*bufId="//' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)".*$/\1/'

Comment: You could just use an XML parser and implement it in one single line!
This will also provide more robust solutions in case you have another attribute `evilAttribute` containing values like `bufld` for example that might trick `awk` or `sed`

Answer (score 3):

with `gawk`

```
awk '{print gensub(/.*bufId="([0-9]*)"/,"\\1",1)}'
```

if you want the result to be quoted you have to capture the quotes as well.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a close approximation of what you were after. Not sure `awk` is going to be your best tool for this.

```
echo '<root><a bufId="123456"/></root>' | awk 'match($0, /bufId="/) { print substr($0, RSTART+7, RLENGTH-1)}'
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957684/awk-access-captured-group-from-line-pattern) was a helpful starting point.

Comment: This also requires `gawk` -- worth mentioning since `mawk` is default awk on Ubuntu, at least.

Comment: Are you sure? Works on macOS, which has the BSD awk, not gnu awk.

Comment: no I'm wrong, sorry.  I believe the way you're using `match`, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

Also with `gawk` (third param in `match` is specific to it):

```
~/test£ cat test
abc
~/test£ gawk '{ match($0, /a(.)(.)/, group)}{ print group[2] group[1]}' test
cb
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going for a `awk` solution for this I would highly recommend using an `XML` parser:

```
$ cat file.xml
<elems><elem bufId="123456"/></elems>

$ xmllint --xpath "concat('\"',string(//elem/@bufId),'\"')" file.xml
"123456"

$ xmllint --xpath "string(//elem/@bufId)" file.xml
123456
```

Depending on if you want to have quotes in your output or not.

Another valid solution would be to use `sed` (if you really dislike XPATH and XML parser, and since there are already many good `awk` solutions I will introduce this one as well):

```
$ sed -n 's/^.*bufId="\([0-9]*\)".*$/\1/gp' file.xml
123456

$ sed -n 's/^.*bufId="\([0-9]*\)".*$/"\1"/gp' file.xml
"123456
```

Comment: An XML parser to parse XML?  Have you gone completely mad!?

Comment: thank you for this.  I posed my own grep/sed solution above, I was hoping for something simpler.  I hadn't thought of an xml parser.  I could do it in perl ... but it wouldn't be a one-liner ...