# Better regular expression to get a value in parenthesis

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I have a M3U playlist that looks something like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="wsoc.us" tvg-name="ABC 9 (Something) (WSOC)" tvg-logo="" group-title="US Locals",ABC 9 (Something) WSOC (WSOC) 
http://some.url/1
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="wbtv.us" tvg-name="CBS 3 WBTV (WBTV)" tvg-logo="" group-title="US Locals",CBS 3 WBTV (WBTV)
http://some.url/2
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="wcnc.us" tvg-name="NBC (Hey) 36 WCNC (WCNC)" tvg-logo="" group-title="US Locals (Something here)",NBC 36 (Hey) WCNC (WCNC)
http://some.url/3
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="wjzy.us" tvg-name="FOX 46 WJZY (Shout Out) (WJZY)" tvg-logo="" group-title="US Locals",FOX 46 WJZY (Shout Out) (WJZY)
http://some.url/4
```

I'm looking to get the last entry in the tvg-name field without the parenthesis - for example, WSOC and WBTV and WCNC, etc.

This works:

```
grep -Po 'tvg-name=\".*?\"'  Playlist.m3u | awk -F'(' '{print $NF}' | cut -f1 -d")" | sort -u
```

But I know there has got to be a better than using grep, awk, and cut.   It's been driving me nuts.

Comment: There's m3u parsers out there

Comment: your code includes a `sort -u` on the end; can the input file contain duplicate `tvg-name` fields? if the answer is 'yes', please update the question a) to include an input with a duplicate `tvg-name`, b) to show the expected output and c) to explicitly mention that you want a unique list; also ... do you need the final output to be sorted?

Comment: Is the trailing space in row two intentional?

Comment: Having exactly the same target string appear twice in each line (e.g. on line 2 `WSOC` appears in `tvg-name="ABC 9 (Something) (WSOC)"` and also in `group-title="US Locals",ABC 9 (Something) WSOC (WSOC)`) makes this a bad test case as a script that doesn't do what you want could produce the output you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Using just a regex with `GNU` `grep`:

```
grep -oP 'tvg-name.*\(\K\w+(?=\))' /tmp/file.m3u
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `tvg-name` | 'tvg-name' |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\(` | ( |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and [Support of K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `\w+` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `(?=` | [look ahead](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is: |
| `\)` | ) |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |

##### Or using [a proper m3u parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::M3U::Extended):

Need to install `CPAN` module

```
cpan Parse::M3U::Extended
```

:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Parse::M3U::Extended qw(m3u_parser);
use File::Slurp;
use feature 'say';
my $m3u = read_file('/tmp/file.m3u');
my @items = m3u_parser($m3u);

foreach my $item (@items) {
    if ($item->{type} eq "directive" and $item->{tag} eq "EXTINF") {
        $_ = $item->{value};
        s/.*\((\w+)\)/$1/;
        say;
    }
}
```

This have the advantage to be reusable for other use-cases in a reliable way, that is not the case with random `awk`, `sed` etc...

##### Output:

```
WSOC 
WBTV
WCNC
WJZY
```

Comment: The single grep line is exactly what I was looking for.   For this particular use case I don't need an M3U parser.   Thanks so much!

Comment: You have the choice ^^

Comment: @GillesQuénot : `m3u8` is such a straight forward format I'm surprised people wrote modules to """"parse"""" it

Answer (score 4):

You can make both `(` and `)` field separators, so you don't need the last `cut`.

You don't need to escape double quotes inside single-quoted strings.

```
grep -Po 'tvg-name=".*?"'  Playlist.m3u | awk -F'[()]' '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

If you're using GNU `awk` you can also use a capture group to get the `tvg-name=".*"` part, so you don't need `grep`.

```
awk 'match($0, /tvg-name="[^"]*\(([^)]*)/, m) { print m[1] }' Playlist.m3u
```

See [AWK: Access captured group from line pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957684/awk-access-captured-group-from-line-pattern)

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `awk`. Use `(` and `)` as field separator and print in every row which contains `tvg-name` second last field (`$(NF-1)`).

```
awk -F '[()]' '/tvg-name/{print $(NF-1)}' Playlist.m3u
```

Output:

```
WSOC
WBTV
WCNC
WJZY
```

Comment: FYI that'd behave the same with any awk, it's not GNU-specific. It's printing the duplicate string from the end of the line though, not the last string in the tvg-name field. idk if that matters to the OP or not.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. Should work in any POSIX `awk` version. using `match` function with `substr` capability here. Using regex  `tvg-name=".*\([^)]*` to match values and out of the printing only required ones.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/ tvg-name=".*\([^)]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*\(/,"",val)
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*tvg-name="[^"]*(\([^)]*\).*/\1/p' file
WSOC
WBTV
WCNC
WJZY
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it the really complex `perl` or `sed` ways, with capturing groups and look-aheads and boundary assertions and what not,

or you can do it the `awk` way :

> ```
> mawk 'NF *= /tvg-name/' FS='.+[(]|[)][^(]*$' OFS=
>
> gawk '$_ = $(NF -= NF^!/tvg-name/)' FS='[#-?]+'
> ```

```
WSOC
WBTV
WCNC
WJZY
```

if you're **ABSOLUTELY** sure nothing is beyond that final `)`, then even cleaner :

> ```
> mawk 'NF *= /tvg-name/' FS='.+[(]|.$' OFS=
> ```

if you modify the `regex` by just a tiny bit, you can even get the broadcast networks ...

> ```
> awk '(NF*=/tvg-name/) && $-_=$--NF' FS='[#-?]+'
> ```

```
WSOC
WBTV
WCNC
WJZY
```

- ... simply by changing that (`#`) to a (`+`) ...

> ```
> awk '(NF*=/tvg-name/) && $-_=$--NF' FS='[+-?]+'  # old solution
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> awk 'NF*=/tvg-name/' FS='.+,| .+$' OFS=          # more succinct
> ```

```
ABC 
CBS 
NBC 
FOX
```

or change it slightly for easy capture of components without needing a dedicated `M3U` parser or using capture groups :

> ```
> awk 'NF*=/tvg-name/' FS='.+,| ([(][^)]+[)] ?)*' OFS='|'
> ```

```
|ABC|9|WSOC|
|CBS|3|WBTV|
|NBC|36|WCNC|
|FOX|46|WJZY|
```

Comment: Small question, What does this part do? `$-_=$--NF`

Comment: @Thefourthbird :  since i never defined `_`, it's the so called `awk null object` which is simultaneously a numeric `0` and an empty string `""`. `$-_` forces it to be numeric `-0` (negative zero), so that whole thing is for overwriting `$0` so it would print out the new column value, and is identical to `$+_=$--NF`. `TL;DR` it's a short hand way to write `{ print $--NF }`. The `"-"` is only needed because `nawk` gives a strange fatal error message while `mawk` refuses to print without it. both are out of compliance with `POSIX`. if you're on `gawk`, just `$_=$--NF` suffices.

Comment: @Thefourthbird : doing a decrement to `NF` is safe here since the first part of the `&&` (logical `AND`) condition already guarantees  `0 < NF` …. which reminded me i was being too verbose with my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk`, if you want to get the last entry in the tvg-name field, you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to not match a double quote and then capture the value between the last occurrence of the parenthesis using a capture group and the [match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-match_0028_0029-function) function:

The pattern matches:

- `\y` A [word boundary](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html) to prevent a partial word match
- `tvg-name="` Match literally
- `[^"]*` Match optional characters other than `"`
- `\(` Match `(`
- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word characters in **group 1**
- `\)` Match `)`

For example

```
awk 'match($0, /\ytvg-name="[^"]*\((\w+)\)/, a) {print a[1]}' Playlist.m3u
```

Output

```
WSOC
WBTV
WCNC
WJZY
```

Another variation matching any character between the parenthesis using a negated character class:

```
awk 'match($0, /\ytvg-name="[^"]*\(([^()]+)\)/, a) {print a[1]}' Playlist.m3u
```